# Application terminate when cropping Image

Tags: java, android

I am having an Application which captures an `image` and send the `ImageUri` to `Crop Intent` for cropping. Some of the photos are getting cropped properly. When there is a change in resolution Application(i.e. Photo taken using front camera with different `resolution` or Uploading a downloaded images) is getting terminated automatically without any error.

**Code to open Camera**

```
fabcamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Open Camera and upload the photo
            Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_CAPTURE);

        }
    });
```

---

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri){
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 0);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 0);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

}
```

---

```
fabgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Open Gallery and upload the photo
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"),SELECT_FILE);

        }
    });
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: "without any error": do you mean there is nothing in logcat?

Comment: Yes with no logcat even. Only for some images.

Comment: Currently, Android doesn't have [CROP intent](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Using another crop library will help to produce crop feature such as [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). And don't use 'android-studio' tag unless your problem related to Android Studio. 'android' tag is enough in your case.

Comment: I understood Thank you.